# location of new Icons to the desktop

Tags: macos

All new icons are now piling on top of one another on top of my Hardrive icon.  How do I fix this? I did not see a similar question when I googled it.

Comment: Is the rest of your desktop clear, or is there at least space for new icons elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Control click on the desktop away from any icon and select **Clean Up By** and choose one of the options. This will test that the desktop file is viable.

If it isn't you can delete it or run Disk Utility to repair the volume

Open terminal and type

```
rm ~/Desktop/.DS_Store
```

Then try to move icons or clean up again. You can then choose to keep things arranged or use clean up periodically or arrange them by hand.